# Plot a 3D point using matplotlib and arrays with numpy in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I want to plot a point with an array using matplotlib, but it fails to read the array for data.

A test case is provided here, where if I use `plt.plot([1], [1], [1], 'or')` it works, but if I use `plt.plot(Point[0], Point[1], Point[2], 'or')` it fails generating the error:

> TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()

Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help!

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

ax.set_xlim3d(0,3)
ax.set_ylim3d(0,3)
ax.set_zlim3d(0,3)

Point = np.array([1,1,1])
plt.plot([1], [1], [1], 'or')
plt.plot(Point[0], Point[1], Point[2], 'or')

plt.show()
```

Comment: It fails because `.plot()` expects a sequence of points, and `Point[0]` is not a sequence.

Comment: Please provide the exact error that it raises.

Comment: Can you suggest me a way to use the data I put in Point in order for it to work? Sorry if it may be too easy, but I am really new in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @cel told in the comments plot expects sequence of points. Try this for instance:

```
plt.plot([[1]], [[1]], [[1]], 'or')
plt.plot([Point[0]], [Point[1]], [Point[2]], 'or')
```